# Where is the correct place to put this return statement?

Tags: java

I am trying to solve the simple two sum problem. However, my trouble is in figuring out where to put the return statement that returns the array. If I put the return statement within the if statement I get a missing return statement error. If I put the return statement right after the if statement, then I get a cannot find symbol error. If I put the return statement right before the end of the method, I get the same cannot find symbol error. I cannot add an else statement because there is no other array that I wish to return if the condition in the if statement is not met, and I am required to return an array. It seems that wherever I put this return statement I get an error. Is there a correct place to put it or is my implementation totally wrong.
I would really appreciate suggestions from anyone.
Thank you!

Note: I understand that this solution probably doesn't solve the two sum problem but I would just like to get this code running so that I can see what is wrong with my logic so that I can improve it.

```
class Solution {
    
    public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        
        for (int i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {
            if(nums[i] + nums[i++] == target) {
                int[] solutions = new int[] {nums[i], nums[i++]};
                return solutions;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to return in case there is no solution? `null`? An empty array`Do you want to throw an exception? The caller will expect some return value (even if `null`), so not returning a return value is not an option.

Comment: (There are, as you say, some other problems with your code, but you will discover soon enough. I think we’re doing you the greatest favour by *not* spelling them out here. You will learn more from discovering yourself.)

Comment: Thank you for your comments. They were very helpful, and I think it's best to figure out the rest of the problems on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your function is defined to return an int[] you have to return it in any case, not only if a particular condition applies.

I am not good at Java, but structure wise, here you have changes I think would solve your issue in comments:

```
class Solution {
    
    public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        // Define here variable which contains what you would return. 
        // Give it a null, or dummy value what would be returned if your condition is not met.
           
        for (int i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {
            if(nums[i] + nums[i++] == target) {
                // Here you should assign values to the array, not create
                                int[] solutions = new int[] {nums[i], nums[i++]};
                return solutions; // remove return from here
            }
        }
        // here right before closing the function, is where return should be.
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. They were very helpful. I know this was  probably not the best question but I appreciate you taking the time to help out a beginner!

Comment: My pleasure, we all were beginners at some point, or still are in other areas ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just place `return` statement inside a loop and at the end of the method any `error` marker - `null` value or `throw RuntimeException()`.

```
/**
 * @return array with exactly two elements or {@literal null} if not found
 */
public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
    Set<Integer> unique = new HashSet<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        int diff = target - nums[i];

        if (unique.contains(diff))
            return new int[] { nums[i], diff };

        unique.add(nums[i]);
    }

    return null;  // could be: an empty array, exception,...
}
```